# Setting constraints to sap.m.DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, sapui5

How do I get my DatePicker to implement my minimum and maximum date constraint?

If an unallowed date is chosen, I preferably do not even want it to trigger a change event, or at least revert the date to one that is allowed. I use 2-way binding, so if I change the date, the date in my model also changes.

```
   var oData = {
       "minimumConstraint" : "2010-01-01",
       "maximumConstraint" : "2020-01-01",
       "displayDate" : "2015-01-01"
     };

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);

sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

var oDatePicker = new sap.m.DatePicker({
  displayFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy",
  valueFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
  value: {path: "displayDate"}
});
```

I also tried some variations of implementing **sap.ui.model.type.Date(oFormatOptions?, oConstraints?)**, but it does not work:

```
var oDatePicker = new sap.m.DatePicker({
  displayFormat: "dd-MM-yyyy",
  valueFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd",
  value: {path: "displayDate",
          type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
                constraints: {
                      minimum: { path: "minimumConstraint"},
                      maximum: { path: "maximumConstraint"}
                            }
                 })
          }
});
```

Comment: The only quick and dirty solution I once came up with was do the check in the event, and set it back to the previous date if violated the constraints. Drawback of course is the popup is closed, hence I understand your need for catching before the event... Would love to know a solution too!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can resolve your problem. I declare a date type outside the definition of the datepicker.

In this example maximumDate = actual date and  minimumDate = actual date less 15 days:

```
var maximumDate = new Date();
var minimumDate = new Date();
minimumDate = minimumDate.setDate(minimumDate.getDate()-15);
var dateType = new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
        pattern: "dd/MM/yyyy",
        strictParsing: true
    }, {
        maximum: maximumDate,
        minimum: minimumDate
    });
```

Now just declare the datepicker with the date type.

```
var oDatePicker = new sap.m.DatePicker(this.createId("datePickerTest"), {
        type: "Date",
        width: '200px',
        value: {
            path:"/dateValue", 
            type: dateType
        },
        placeholder: "Date"
    });
```

To see this working you can add validation functions.

```
oDatePicker.attachValidationError(function(oEvent) {
        var oElement = oEvent.getParameter("element");
        oElement.setValueState("Error");
    });
oDatePicker.attachValidationSuccess(function(oEvent) {
    var oElement = oEvent.getParameter("element");
    oElement.setTooltip("");
    oElement.setValueState("None");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example (see this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/rufosonosi/edit?html,output)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Demo</title>

    <script src="https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-preload="sync">
            </script>

    <script>

      var oData = {
         minimumConstraint : "2015-08-01",
         maximumConstraint : "2015-08-31",
         displayDate : "2015-08-10"
      };

      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData);
      sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);

      var oDatePicker = new sap.m.DatePicker({
        width: '200px',
        value: {
            path:"/displayDate",
            type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
                pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd",
                source: {
                    pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
                strictParsing: true
              }, {
                maximum: oModel.getProperty("/maximumConstraint"),
                minimum: oModel.getProperty("/minimumConstraint")
              })
        },
        placeholder: "Date"
      });

      oDatePicker.attachValidationError(function(oEvent) {
        var oElement = oEvent.getParameter("element");
        var sMinDate = oModel.getProperty("/minimumConstraint");
        var sMaxDate = oModel.getProperty("/maximumConstraint");
        oElement.setValueState("Error");
        oElement.setValueStateText("Enter date between " + sMinDate + " and " + sMaxDate);
      });
      oDatePicker.attachValidationSuccess(function(oEvent) {
        var oElement = oEvent.getParameter("element");
        oElement.setValueState("None");
        oElement.setValueStateText(null);
      });

      oDatePicker.placeAt("content");

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```